# Chrome app does not affect the page of the current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am creating a chrome extension app. This is how the app works:
When I click a button on the side bar, it runs a function called `translator` and change every text node into "test..."

When I run the function on console, it runs perfectly fine. But when I run it by clicking the button on the side bar, it runs but does not affect the appearance of the current working page.

Here are my codes:
**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "webpage translator",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
  ],

  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/test_icon.jpg", 
    "48": "icons/test_icon.jpg", 
    "128": "icons/test_icon.jpg"
  },

  "sidebar_action": {
    "default_page": "sidebar.html",  
    "default_icon": {         
        "16": "icons/test_icon.jpg"
    },

    "default_title": "test",     
    "use_navigation_bar": true       
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ]
}
```

**sidebar.js**

```
import translator from "./translator.js";

const button = document.getElementById('test_button');

button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
  });
  console.log('current tab: ', tab);
  console.log('translator function: ', translator);
  
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: translator
  });
})

console.log('starting sidebar.js...')
```

**translator.js**

```
async function translate(node) {
  node.textContent = 'test';
}

async function checkChildNodes(node) {
  if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    for (let childNode of node.childNodes) {
      console.log("checking node...")
      checkChildNodes(childNode);
    }
  }
  else {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      console.log('Text exists...!');
      console.log(node.textContent);
      node.textContent = 'test....!';
      translate(node);
    }
  }
}

async function translator() {
  console.log('running translator...')
  const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (let div of divs) {
    checkChildNodes(div);
  }
}

export default translator;
```

When I check the console of the current tab, I see "running translator..." message just fine. But it does not affect the text nodes of the current tab. I am quite new to chrome extension app so I must be missing something but I could not find any solution for the issue online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't reference outside functions in the injected code. Put all code you want to run inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by putting in all the functions in **translator.js** to the function `translator`.

Here is my revised code:
**translator.js**

```
async function translator() {
  async function translate(node) {
    node.textContent = 'test';
  }
  
  async function checkChildNodes(node) {
    console.log('running checkChildNodes...!')
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
      for (let childNode of node.childNodes) {
        console.log("checking node...")
        checkChildNodes(childNode);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        console.log('Text exists...!');
        console.log(node.textContent);
        node.textContent = 'test....!';
        translate(node);
      }
    }
  }

  const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  console.log("running translator...!")
  for (let div of divs) {
    checkChildNodes(div);
  }
}

export default translator
```